# How to convert timestamp string to millisecond int

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the Stopwatch Timer plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/stop_watch_timer)
This plugin gives me time elapsed as a 'string'.
So my text looks like:

```
00:00:03.45 // hours:minutes:seconds.milliseconds
```

Now I need to use this time information to calculate the score in the game.
Do you know how I can convert this string into millisecond int so that i can use it to do math calculations?

My logic would be to multiple the time taken with another value to determine the score. THe more time user takes, the higher (poor) the score would be.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use DateFormat like this:

```
final timeStr = '00:00:03.45';
final format = DateFormat('HH:mm:ss.S');
final dt = format.parse(timeStr, true);
print(dt.millisecondsSinceEpoch);
```

which would print:

```
3045
```

**Note**: Will require intl package to be imported:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

Comment: This is definitely the cleanest solution, nice!

Comment: Yes simple and clean.

Comment: Thanks, but not clean enough apparently :)

Comment: @ssdesign, on a side note.. a quick look at the package shows that you can get the milliseconds straight away, without parsing for it. I can obviously not know how you use the lib, but the rawTime property holds the milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Duration()` and get the milliseconds like this.

I use time as `10:12:23.24` and split through every item and get hr, min, sec, millisec.

```
void main() {
String test = "10:12:23.24";
String hr = test.split(":")[0];
// print(hr);
String minutes = test.split(":")[1];
// print(minutes);
String seconds = test.split(":")[2].split(".")[0];
// print(seconds);
String milliseconds = test.split(":")[2].split(".")[1];
// print(milliseconds);

Duration duration = Duration(
  hours: int.tryParse(hr) ?? 0,
  minutes: int.tryParse(minutes) ?? 0,
  seconds: int.tryParse(seconds) ?? 0,
  milliseconds: int.tryParse(milliseconds) ?? 0);
  print(duration.inMilliseconds);
}
```

Output will be in milliseconds: `36743024` <- Output

You can try [here](https://dartpad.dev/134e6df5958b026c46fd90aa581d0a93?null_safety=true)

Comment: WOW, thats a really elegant solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A quite manual but functional solution to this, using `Duration`, would be something like

```dart
  Duration getDuration(String elapsed) {
    List<String> splits = elapsed.split(':');
    List<String> minSplits = splits[2].split('.');

    int hours = int.parse(splits[0]);
    int minutes = int.parse(splits[1]);
    int seconds = int.parse(minSplits[0]);
    
    // pad with 0s to make sure 45 -> 450
    int millis = int.parse(minSplits[1].padRight(3, '0'));
    
    // create a duration object for ease of calculation/access
    Duration duration = Duration(
      hours: hours,
      minutes: minutes,
      seconds: seconds,
      milliseconds: millis,
    );
    
    return duration;
  }
  
  
  
  String elapsed = '00:00:03.45';
  Duration duration = getDuration(elapsed);
  print(duration.inMilliseconds);
```